# How to Disable the DialogFlow ChatBot on Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, messenger

I just installed dialogflow on facebook messenger and it works great.
My problem is that I want to pass the chat to a human agent, but I can't find a way to stop the DialogFlow chat from giving the responses.

For example, if a customer wants to buy a cell phone, then this should be passed to a human agent, and when the customer writes Cell Phone again, do not repeat the same DialogFlow phrase.

I've been watching several videos and I can't find the clear solution.

I have tried several things like activate as main receiver but I am missing as the trigger word to stop typing the Dialogflow chat.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you solved this on your own. But the easiest way to do so would be by creating a context that prevents the bot from responding in certain ways. You could do this in two ways:

1. No code approach. In this case set an output context when the user lands on an intent which must be handled by sales. Create an input context for all other intents which will make them unable to be triggered unless that is true. This will require some finesse and fine tuning.
2. Code. You can set an active context and name it via the fullfillment editor. You can also determine how long this should remain active. If you have set up  all your intents to require a different input context, then they should not trigger and the bot will send any request to fallback. Alternatively you could set up an intent that is triggered only when this context is active and use it to provide support messages to the user.